# Decrypt a encrypted secret using PyCrypto AES & sha256

Tags: python, encryption, aes, sha256

I have a encrypted message in a file, encrypted by the following code.
I wrote a function to decrypt this message. I know the password used to encrypt it.

But I got the following error:

```
python3 decrypt.py enim_msg.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypt.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(":: Decrypted: \n" + bytes.decode(decrypted))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix this problem pls ?
Is My decrypt function wrong ?

## My code :

### Encrypt function

```py
import os
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

def encrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64*1024
    outputFile = "en" + filename
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = Random.new().read(16)

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

def getKey(password):
    hasher = SHA256.new(password.encode('utf-8'))
    return hasher.digest()
```

### Decrypt function I wrote

```py
def decrypt(enc, password):
    #print(":: enc => " + enc)
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    return cipher.decrypt(enc[16:])
```

### How I call this function

```py
password = "azerty123"
secret_file_path = sys.argv[1]

the_file = open(secret_file_path, "rb")
encrypted = the_file.read()
decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password)
the_file.close()

print(":: Decrypted: \n" + bytes.decode(decrypted))
```

Comment: I don't know much Python - but I do know that storing anything as a string when it comes to encryption is a bad idea.  Encrypted data, keys etc. are all binary data by nature - you should store them this way too.  You can't convert arbitrary binary to a string and back.

Comment: Wow, I've seen many "unbalanced" encrypt / decrypt functions, but this one takes the biscuit. As a developer, how can you even *think* this is going to work? Your encrypt / decrypt functions should do the same thing in reverse. Why is `filesize` a string?

Comment: Oh, I see, it's just suboptimal in the sense that it is a decimal string of 16 bytes / characters. Yuk. I don't see any place where you handle this during decryption. The way chunks are possibly padding with spaces is absolutely wrong, and not fully retrieved chunks may let this function fail spectacularly, e.g. when the buffer size is anything than a multiple of the block size. The encryption is just a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [bytes.decrypt()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) function by default expects an UTF-8 encoded string. But not every sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 sequence. In your case `cipher.decrypt()` (which may return *any* sequence of bytes) returned a byte-sequence, which is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Thus the `bytes.decode()` function raised an error.

The actual reason why `cipher.decrypt()` returned a non-UTF-8 string is a bug in your code:

Your encrypted file format contains non-utf-8 data. Its format is like:

- 16 bytes len info (unencrypted, UTF-8 encoded)
- 16 bytes IV (unencrypted, binary i.e. non-UTF-8 encoded)
- n bytes payload (encrypted, UTF-8 encoded)

You have to ensure that on decryption you only decode parts of your file, that are UTF-8 encoded. Furthermore you have to ensure that you decrypt only encrypted parts of your file (as mentioned in your comments)